# How do we train a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

Yes, it's a very basic question, but I'm not sure if I'm undertanding the process.

I feed my network with the first observation, with random W for each neuron. I get a predicition, with an error. Then comes all the iterative process of adjusting the W values (backpropagation,  gradient descending, learning rate..), until I have an aceptable error for this single observation (or I have performed a max numbers of iterations). Is that correct?

Then...? I feed the network with the next observation, starting with the W values calculated in previous one observation, and repeat the adjusting process, until I get new W's that minimize the error for this new observation? This changes the W values for many (or almost all) neurons...

So the idea of a al the process is that, after feeding my network with all observations (training data) the W's of all neurons **CONVERGE** to a set of values that gives me a valid prediction to all (or a acceptable percentage of) future observation?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite. The weights are not optimized after each observation, but rather adjusted by a single (small) gradient descent step based on a set of observations (called a mini-batch). Repeating this process leads to minimization of the error over the entire training set.

Comment: @J.Delaney I don't understand... If I feed it with a mini-batch... Which one is the error I must minimize? The average? What W's are calculated? As I understand, they are adjusted for a set of X that correspond to a single observation...